# HTML body and XLSX attachment in mail via UNIX using SENDMAIL command

Tags: unix, sendmail

I am trying to send a mail via UNIX with HTML body and xlsx file as attachment, but I am not able to attach the file with the mail, can anybody share some sample code? This is what I have tried, I have to send the XLSX file as attachment for simplicity I am trying it with CSV,
Unix var file is a CSV file which contains data as abc,xyz@gmail.com

```
echo $file
while read LINE
do
echo $LINE;
fund_provider_code=`echo $LINE | awk -F',' '{print$1}'`
len=`echo $fund_provider_code | awk '{print length}'`
length=`expr $len + 2`
email_list=`echo $LINE | cut -c $length-`
echo fund_code=$fund_provider_code
email=$email_list
(BOUNDARY='=== This is the boundary between parts of the message. ==='
ATTACHMENT="$attachment_file"
SUBJECT="$subject_text"
VERSION=1.0
print -  'To:' ${email_list}
print -  'Subject:' ${SUBJECT}
print -  'MIME-Version: 1.0'
print -  'Content-Type: MULTIPART/MIXED; '
print -  'Content-Type: TEXT/HTML; charset=US-ASCII'
print -
awk -v message1="${msg1}"  ' BEGIN {
print "<html><body>"
print "<style>"
print "p.MsoNormal, li.MsoNormal, div.MsoNormal \{mso-style-parent:\"\";   margin:0in; margin-bottom:.0001pt; mso-pagination:widow-orphan; font-size:12.0pt;font-family:\"Arial\"; mso-fareast-font-family:\"MSMincho\";\}"
print "</style>"
print "<div class=Section1>"
print "<p class=MsoNormal style=\"mso-layout-grid-align:none;text-autospace:none\"><span style=\"font-size:12.0pt;font-family:'Arial';mso-bidi-font-family:'Arial'; color:Black\">Dear All,<o:p></o:p></span></p>"
print "</div></body></html>"
}' email_body.txt;
print -
print -  "--${BOUNDARY}--"
print -  'ATTACH="/projects/dit/edw/EDW_OUTBOUND_FEEDS/bin/email.csv"'
print -  'Content-Type: TEXT/HTML, multipart/mixed, text/html, application/octet-stream ; name=email.csv'
print -  "Content-Transfer-Encoding: base64"
print -  'Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=abc.csv'
uuencode "/projects/dit/edw/EDW_OUTBOUND_FEEDS/bin/email.csv" email.csv
print -
print -  "--${BOUNDARY}--"
) | sendmail ${email_list}
done < "$file"
```

Comment: Stack Overflow is not a code writing service. Please make an attempt to do this yourself, and then post if you can't do it.

Comment: @thesecretmaster - done, posted the code.

Comment: Thank you! I've removed my downvote.

Comment: Do you have a [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)? this could help you solve your problem yourself.

Comment: @J.Chomel - updated the code, have a look now

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you have a discrepancy in the filename you want to send. The below assume you want to send file locally defined as:

```
/projects/dit/edw/EDW_OUTBOUND_FEEDS/bin/email.csv
```

--- however, you hadn't defined it properly, so I fixed the assignment so:

```
ATTACH="/projects/dit/edw/EDW_OUTBOUND_FEEDS/bin/email.csv"
```

Or did you want to use ATTACHMENT? I think you must clean this code.

- I found no use of this line:

```
    ATTACHMENT="$attachment_file"
```

- var `subject_text` isn't defined, or is it in a part of the script we don't see in your OP?
- var `attachment_file` isn't defined either.

I think you should use the file you want to send in a var: `$ATTACH`

```
echo $file
while read LINE
do
echo $LINE;
fund_provider_code=`echo $LINE | awk -F',' '{print$1}'`
len=`echo $fund_provider_code | awk '{print length}'`
length=`expr $len + 2`
email_list=`echo $LINE | cut -c $length-`
echo fund_code=$fund_provider_code
email=$email_list
(BOUNDARY='=== This is the boundary between parts of the message. ==='
ATTACHMENT="$attachment_file"
ATTACH="/projects/dit/edw/EDW_OUTBOUND_FEEDS/bin/email.csv"
SUBJECT="$subject_text"
VERSION=1.0
print -  'To:' ${email_list}
print -  'Subject:' ${SUBJECT}
print -  'MIME-Version: 1.0'
print -  'Content-Type: MULTIPART/MIXED; '
print -  'Content-Type: TEXT/HTML; charset=US-ASCII'
print -
awk -v message1="${msg1}"  ' BEGIN {
print "<html><body>"
print "<style>"
print "p.MsoNormal, li.MsoNormal, div.MsoNormal \{mso-style-parent:\"\";   margin:0in; margin-bottom:.0001pt; mso-pagination:widow-orphan; font-size:12.0pt;font-family:\"Arial\"; mso-fareast-font-family:\"MSMincho\";\}"
print "</style>"
print "<div class=Section1>"
print "<p class=MsoNormal style=\"mso-layout-grid-align:none;text-autospace:none\"><span style=\"font-size:12.0pt;font-family:'Arial';mso-bidi-font-family:'Arial'; color:Black\">Dear All,<o:p></o:p></span></p>"
print "</div></body></html>"
}' email_body.txt;
print -
print -  "--${BOUNDARY}--"
print -  'ATTACH="${ATTACH}"'
print -  'Content-Type: TEXT/HTML, multipart/mixed, text/html, application/octet-stream ; name="'$(basename ${ATTACH})'"'
print -  "Content-Transfer-Encoding: base64"
print -  'Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="'$(basename ${ATTACH})'"'
uuencode $ATTACH $(basename ${ATTACH})
print -  "--${BOUNDARY}--"
) | sendmail ${email_list}
done < "$file"
```

From [examples](http://www.unix.com/shell-programming-and-scripting/118534-sendmail-attachments.html) I saw, if you use GNU `uuencode`, you may need to replace the line

```
uuencode $ATTACH $(basename $ATTACH)
```

by

```
uuencode --base64 $ATTACH $(basename $ATTACH)
```